Why is the total for gradingrange section1 wrong?
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,addpoints]{exam} 

\begin{document}
    \begin{questions}
        \begingradingrange{section1}
            \question[10] Here is my first question worth 10 points\\
            The number of points in section one are \pointsinrange{section1}
        \endgradingrange{section1}
    \end{questions}
   
    \begin{questions}
        \begingradingrange{section2}
            \question[25]% 
                Here is my second question worth 25
        \endgradingrange{section2}
    \end{questions}
\end{document}

Output

(10 points) Here is my first question worth 10 points
The number of points in section one are 25
(25 points) Here is my second question worth 25

Question why does \pointsinrange{section1} return 25 rather than 10?

Is it for some reason intended to have two sections with one question each? The numbers seem to be correct, if you use only one question section with two questions in it.

It is just a simplification of a much larger exam that has two sections - each section containing multiple questions.
The numbers are not correct, \pointsinrange{section1} returns 25 rather than 10.
